Jest/React-Testing-Library test failing with React component while changing the <title> element inside <head>
I've written some tests for this Title component, but I can't manage to correctly access the <title> inside <head>:
import Title from './Title'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { getByTestId, render, waitFor, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import i18next from 'i18next'

jest.mock('services/SessionService', () => ({
  getFromCache: jest.fn()
}))

const titleWithProps = (props = {}, history) => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Title {...props}>Hello</Title>
    </Router>
  )
}

//jest.mock('axios')
afterEach(cleanup)

describe('Title component', () => {
  it('should render in the DOM', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(titleWithProps())
    const titleComponent = getByTestId('Title')
    expect(titleComponent).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  it('should render children correctly', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    const { getByText } = render(titleWithProps({}, history))
    expect(getByText('Hello')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  it('should set the correct title on initial render', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    render(titleWithProps({}, history))
    const helmet = Helmet.peek()
    expect(helmet.title).toBe('NTK Institute')
  })

  it('should update title based on pathname', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ['/'] })
    const { rerender } = render(titleWithProps({}, history))
    history.push('/new-path')
    rerender(titleWithProps({}, history))
    const helmet = Helmet.peek()
    expect(helmet.title).toBe('NTK Institute')
  })

  /*   it('should handle article pages correctly', () => {
    const articleTitle = 'Sample Article'
    SessionService.getFromCache.mockReturnValueOnce(articleTitle)
    const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ['/article'] })
    render(titleWithProps({}, history))
    const helmet = Helmet.peek()
    expect(helmet.title).toBe(`NTK Institute | ${articleTitle}`)
  }) */

  it('should handle localized routes correctly', () => {
    i18next.t = jest.fn(key => key)
    const history = createMemoryHistory({
      initialEntries: ['/localized-route']
    })
    render(titleWithProps({}, history))
    const helmet = Helmet.peek()
    expect(helmet.title).toBe('NTK Institute')
  })
})

I particularly need it to test this part of the component's code:
const metaByPath = (pathname, metaTitle) => {
  let title = ''
  const channelName = configuration.localization.brand
  for (const [routesKey, routesVal] of Object.entries(routes)) {
    if (pathname === '/') {
      return i18next.t('homePage', { channelName })
    } else if (pathname.includes(routes.article.name)) {
      const articleTitle = SessionService().getFromCache('article_title', '')
      title = metaTitle
      if (articleTitle !== '') {
        title += ` | ${articleTitle}`
      }
    } else if (pathname.includes(routesVal.name)) {
      return i18next.exists(routesKey)
        ? i18next.t(routesKey, { channelName })
        : metaTitle
    } else {
      title = metaTitle
    }
  }
  return title
}

